# Tab Bar in UItableview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, tabbar

I have written an iPhone app with about 5-6 screens (each is a UITableView). I have finished writing the app, and now the requirement came up to add a tab bar in the 3rd screen.

Basically, the structure of the app is as follows:

**Screen 1**: Name of restaurants (example)

**Screen 2:** On clicking one restaurant, you get a number of options, like 1. location 2. rating 3. cuisine etc. Clicking each of these options shows a separate table view with some information.

Now, I need a Tab Bar in the 3rd level of screens (location,cuisine etc) with the same options.. i.e. location, cuisine etc, so that a user can directly go to that option instead of going to the previous screen first.

How can I implement this in my code? Each of the view is a subclass of UIViewController.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using storyboards or xibs?

Answer (score 1):

Drag in a `UITabBarController` from your Interface Builder. Connect as many ViewControllers as you want to your `UITabBarController`, and connect your 2nd View Controller to your UITabBarController.

**NOTE:**
If you are not comfortable with the `UITabBarController` connections, just start a new XCode project for "Tabbed Application" and consider it as a starting point to your app (for inits and connections)

Comment: When you say "connect your 2nd view controller" , you mean via a segue, right?

Now my second view controller will have two emerging segues, and due to the code, it is always going to the second one.

Comment: Yes, I mean via segue. Consider creating a tabbed application template within XCode and inspect it. You will get to create an easy one for yourself.